# Placing Randomly and different sizes UIImage

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, uiview, uiimageview

I'm trying to achieve something like the following (diamond Images)

[image]

So far I'm able to achieve following using different combinations of stack views

[image]

But that's not perfect result (mediocre at most actually). can anyone guide to better way to achieve this?

Using following stackview configuration
[image]

Comment: It will be useful to post the code that you have. Otherwise it is hard to comment on improvements to your approach.

Comment: @Durstann i have used stackview through storyboard, let me add screen shot in question